# How to remove a segment of string

Tags: string, vb.net, visual-studio

How can i remove a segment of a string. For Example I following strings

+GMCL: 8, ABCD, XYZ, 123

+GMCL: 9, ABCD, XYZ, 123

+GMCL: 10, ABCD, XYZ, 123

+GMCL: 103, ABCD, XYZ, 123

+GMCL: 1015, ABCD, XYZ, 123

How can I get the string after the first comma, I mean I want to remove the part of string till first comma, like I want the following results in my string

ABCD, XYZ, 123

ABCD, XYZ, 123

ABCD, XYZ, 123

ABCD, XYZ, 123

ABCD, XYZ, 123

Thanks

Comment: Search on String.IndexOf and then String.Substring

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the values are stored in some sort of list or array then you can do:

```
Dim resultSet As List(Of String) = 
      list.Select(Function(e) e.Substring(e.IndexOf(",") + 2)) _
          .ToList()
```

Or if you only want to perform the operation on a single string then you can do:

```
Dim result As String = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(",") + 2)
```

Note, for the first example, you'll need to use the import `Imports System.Linq`.